# Service not always restarting, can't get logs

Tags: android, service

I have a service which sends the user's location to the database every minute.  It works for the most part, restarting several times as required.  But eventually it will stop and not restart.  I have managed to work out that when it dies all together it tries to restart but fails.

It stops at random times and takes days to happen, so how could I go about getting the logs from when it happens so I can debug?

Answer (score 1):

We've had some nasty bug introduced by Google on devices with Android 4.4 - 4.4.2 , it was resolved with 4.4.3+.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63793

Are you sure that's not your case?

Comment: It does successfully start most of the time, so I don't think it is that.  Thanks though, will be useful to know when testing later.